# Incrementing a column for rows when record is updated earlier

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a table structure like this:

```
ID (PK), Parent_ID (FK), Title, Position
```

And rows like these:

```
1, 1, Apple, 1
2, 1, Orange, 2
3, 1, Banana, 3
4, 1, Lime, 4
5, 1, Grapefruit, 5
6, 2, Lemon, 1
```

Now, let's say I want to run the following query:

```
UPDATE table SET Position = 1 WHERE ID = 3
```

How do I update the position field for other rows so that the numbers increment properly up to where the record originally was in the position list. Note that this should only effect rows with the same Parent_ID).

So when completed. it will look like this:

```
1, 1, Apple, 2
2, 1, Orange, 3
3, 1, Banana, 1
4, 1, Lime, 4
5, 1, Grapefruit, 5
6, 2, Lemon, 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please double check your expected output. It seems like the first output is the expected output to me.

Comment: Would you only ever set the Position value to 1, and the remember the other rows, or would you want to set any Position value?

Comment: @1000111 - the output looks correct to me. Row 3 now has Positon 1 and the other rows have been changed to remain in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update records where the position is between 1 and 3 (inclusive), but the ID does not equal with the id of the just updated record (3) and also provide the parent_id:

```
UPDATE table SET Position = Position + 1
WHERE ID <> 3 and Position>=1 and Position<3 and Parent_ID=1
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You do need to run several updates of the other rows.

A generic solution :

```
/** initial update or insert **/
UPDATE table SET Position = 1 WHERE ID = 3;

/** update of the other sequence **/
UPDATE table Set Position = CASE WHEN Position >= 1 THEN Position + 1 ELSE Position - 1 End where id <> 3
```